# Turbo Assembler prints previous message when trying to print new message

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I have a program that print some strings it receives as an input.
Here is the full program:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
const_10 db 10

max_pin_len db 6
pin_len db 0
pin db 6 dup('$')

message_1 db 10, 'Print the text $'
message_2 db 10, 'Print the pin $'
message_3 db 10, 'Encrypt: 0, Decrypt: 1 $'
message_4 db 10, 'result: $'
is_encrypt db ?
newline db 13,10, '$'
maxlen db 100
cur_input_len db 0
buf db 100 dup('$') 

CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    lea dx, [message_1]
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    
    mov dl, 10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    
input_str:
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset maxlen
    int 21h
    call NEW_LINE
    lea dx, [buf]
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    call NEW_LINE
    
input_pin:
    lea dx, [message_2]
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    
    mov dl, 10
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset max_pin_len
    int 21h
    
    call NEW_LINE
    lea dx, [pin]
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    call NEW_LINE
    
    
    lea di, [buf]
    mov cx, 0
    mov cl, [cur_input_len] ;the character limit
process:
    mov dl, [di]
    ;print shifted character
    add dl, 5
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    
    inc di
    loop process
    
after:
    call NEW_LINE
    mov dl, [cur_input_len]
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
    
proc PRINT_AL

    ; dived by 10 to get two digits
    MOV AH,0
    DIV [CONST_10] ; al-/   ah=%
    
    ;print ASHAROT
    MOV DX,AX
    ADD DL,'0'
    ADD DH,'0'
    MOV AH,2
    INT 21H
    
    ;PRINT YECHIDOT 
    MOV DL,DH
    INT 21H

    ret
endp

proc NEW_LINE
    lea dx, [newline]
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    ret
endp
END start
```

Now, the problem is in the output. in input_pin, when I call the lines

```
call NEW_LINE
lea dx, [pin]
mov ah, 9
int 21h
call NEW_LINE
```

it outputs:

```
12345
Print the text
```

I never called for it to print the message after the value of pin. Can someone help?
I even printed another message, message_2 before the lines above, and it still prints message 1.

Comment: You are likely receiving the enter (end of line) from the user as well so your buffer isn't big enough and you overwrite all of the `$` you put in there hence the print string function won't find the proper end.

Comment: Hey, that could be the problem. If it is, how do I fix it? (new to assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured out the answer from the comments:
Just make sure that in the variables the size of the buffer is 1 higher than the max size. The new code looks like this:

```
max_pin_len db 6
pin_len db 0
pin db 7 dup('$')
```